# Change in localstorage not triggering event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have React component. Initially I set some localStorage in UseEffect. Moreover I add event listener. After clicking on text it changes the localStorage value but event listener does not triggering, why?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("item 1", 'val 1');
    window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
      alert('localstorage changed!')
    })
  }, []);

  const getData = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("item", "val chamged");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={getData}>Change localstorage value</h1>

    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-engelbart-90tkw

Comment: Please update your codesandbox to be same as the code you have pasted here. There is not event listener in your link sandbox.

Comment: If you change the sandbox code to match what you have here, specifically the `onClick={getData}` part, you will see that it works. There is a typo where you call the `getData()` function and pass the result instead of passing the function itself.

Comment: updated but it still not working

Comment: The useEffect() can not detect the changes. I've tried some random hash to trigger the useEffect https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hawking-hz6pq but still don't know why the listener does nothing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two things wrong.

1. change `onClick={getData()}` `onClick={getData}`
2. From the doc(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event). `The storage event of the Window interface fires when a storage area (localStorage or sessionStorage) has been modified in the context of another document.` Note the last sentence that says it won't be fired in the same document. You can see that if you open https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-browser-89con in 2 tabs in same browser, the alert will start coming.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to fix it to works fine when the changes is done in the same document ?

Comment: It is not required in same document. Cant you invoke the handler function manually after updating localStorage. ? May be write a wrapper function that will set localstorage and invoke your callback.

Answer (score 10):

To update the localStorage in the same window, you need to **dispatch a storage event**. 
I changed some of the values from the original question to update the same cookie that is initially set.
 Don't forget that **event listeners need to be removed** when the component unmounts!

### **useSyncExternalStore (2023)**

With [useSyncExternalStore](https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore#subscribing-to-a-browser-api) it is possible to subscribe to an external store like the browser API. I changed the answer to use one of the most common use cases: Updating and reading data from the localStorage.

```ts
import { useSyncExternalStore } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [localStorageValue, setLocalStorageValue] = useLocalStorage();

  return (
    <div className='App mt-44'>
      <button type='button' onClick={setLocalStorageValue}>
        Change localStorage value
      </button>
      <p>{localStorageValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const useLocalStorage = () => {
  const item = useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot, () => undefined);

  // Parse the json string
  // You should probably further narrow down the JSON.parse type because JSON.parse returns any
  const value = typeof item === "string" ? JSON.parse(item) : null;

  const setValue = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify("new-value"));
    //The event name has to match the eventListeners defined in the subscribe function
    window.dispatchEvent(new StorageEvent("custom-storage-event-name"));
  };

  return [value, setValue] as const;
};

function subscribe(callback: () => void) {
  window.addEventListener("custom-storage-event-name", callback);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("custom-storage-event-name", callback);
  };
}

//Return the current value from the browser API
function getSnapshot() {
  //alert("localStorage changed")
  return localStorage.getItem("item");
}
```

### **Old Answer**

```ts
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {

  //Set localStorage item when the component mounts and add storage event listener
  useEffect(() => {
    const alertMessage = () => {
      alert('localStorage changed!');
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem("item", 'val 1');
    window.addEventListener('custom-storage-event-name', alertMessage);

    //Remove the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("custom-storage-event-name", alertMessage);
    }
  }, []);

  //Update the localStorage onClick
  const updateData = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("item", "val changed");
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("custom-storage-event-name")); //This is the important part
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={updateData}>Change localStorage value</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Best answer yet in that the solution doesn't require a third party package or proxy object and actually works!

Answer (score 2):

The Storage event is triggered when there is a change in the window's storage area.

> **Note:** The storage event is only triggered when a window **other than
>   itself** makes the changes.

You can see more details and demo: [storage Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_storage_url.asp)

The `storage` event handler will only affect other windows. Whenever something changes in one window inside `localStorage` all the other windows are notified about it and if any action needs to be taken it can be achieved by a handler function listening to the `storage` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this onclick handler

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("item 1", 'val 1');
    window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
      alert('localstorage changed!')
    })
  }, []);

  const getData = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("item", "val chamged");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={()=>getData()}>Change localstorage value</h1>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `onClick={()=>getData()}` is same as `onClick={getData}`

Comment: Subin, it's even better to don't create redundant anonymous function if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a solution. It might be an ugly solution, but it is the only solution that I have found to achieve it from the same window. (for some reasons I need to get the change :) )

I've used the MutationObserver class, for example to get any changes on the dark mode value:

```
const setTheme = (value) => {
    let htmlClasses = document.querySelector('html').classList
    if (value == true) {
        htmlClasses.add('dark');
    } else {
        htmlClasses.remove('dark');
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem('dark', value)
}
```

Here I am adding a class each time the toggle button has been activated, then I configure an observer on the html classes like this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      console.log(mutation);
      if (mutation.attributeName == "class") {
         // Do what you want here
      }
  });
});
var config = {
  attributes: true
};

observer.observe(document.querySelector('html'), config);
```

You can see also an other example (more useful for you) that I've found on github [here](https://github.com/jamiewilson/reference/blob/master/js-mutation-observer-localstorage.html)